# Need help adding tracking code to Pug file in Express app

Tags: express, pug, hubspot

I have a single page Express app and I am leveraging Pug for my template engine. I am trying to add a HubSpot tracking code to my app and I am having a hard time with the syntax. Here is my Pug file:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head 
        title Update account info
    body
        div.container 
          p User: #{userEmail}
          p Favorite Food: #{favoriteFood}
          form(method="POST")
              label(for="newVal") New favorite food 
              input(type="text" name="newVal")
```

Here is the tracking code I am trying to embed:

```
<!-- Start of HubSpot Embed Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async defer src="//js.hs-scripts.com/test.js"></script>
<!-- End of HubSpot Embed Code -->
```

The HubSpot tracking code instructions:

> Copy and paste this tracking code into every page of your site, just before the `</body>` tag.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the script tags according to the pug syntax as below. If you're new to `Pug` you can use a HTML to pug converter like [this](https://html-to-pug.com/).

```
...
...
body
    div.container 
      p User: #{userEmail}
      p Favorite Food: #{favoriteFood}
      form(method="POST")
          label(for="newVal") New favorite food 
          input(type="text" name="newVal")
    <!-- Start of HubSpot Embed Code -->
    script#hs-script-loader(type="text/javascript" async defer src="//js.hs-scripts.com/test.js")
    <!-- End of HubSpot Embed Code -->
```

The Pug [documentation](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) should be good to quickly get a hand-on with the template syntax.